# Rewrite html files in root to directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I'm in need of some assistance. 
Problem:
I have now made my site multilingual using a CMS which processes everything at index.php
I am trying to redirect all .html pages being accessed from root,like

http://www.website.com/englishpage.html 
I want to redirect it to
http://www.website.com/en/englishpage.html

and then a secondary redirect will dissect that information and send it to index.php which will then serve the correct page.

Right now, I'm getting too many redirect errors

```
# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ en/$1\.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|ru)?(\/)?(.*)$ index.php?c=$1&q=$3 [L,QSA]
```

what am i doing wrong here

thanks

Comment: Hard to say. You say "`http://www.website.com/englishpage.html` I want to redirect it to `http://www.website.com/en/englishpage.html`" But, your rewrite rules say other thing. So, give some real URL examples. For example: `http://www.website.com/englishpage.html` to `http://www.website.com/index.php?page=englishpage.html&whatever=whatever` The rules are not a good way to **guess** what's needed, specially when they don't work.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Essentially the CMS i am using will grab the correct content according to two variables: the context and the query. The context portion is signified in the apparent directory of the request, like /en/ for English and /ru/ for Russian. The remainder of the query is the page name/alias.

So a request such as http://www.website.com/ru/english.html

would actually mean http://www.website.com/index.php?c=ru&q=english.html

hope that clarifies it :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.*\.html)` is not specific enough and therefore also matches `/en/englishpage.html`. It also keeps on adding `.html` to the end.

So `/englishpage.html` redirect to `/en/englishpage.html.html`, which redirect to `/en/en/englishpage.html.html.html` etc.

To fix both problems:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ en/$1\.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^((en|ru)/)?(.*)$ index.php?c=$1&q=$3 [L,QSA]
```

PS no need to escape a `/`

Comment: Thank you Gerben, it helped :) I still had use this line:
    `RewriteRule ^(en|ru)?(\/)?(.*)$ index.php?c=$1&q=$3 [L,QSA]`
to get it work, for some reason with the line you suggested it forwarded all requests to /ru/ 

As for:
`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ en/$1\.html [R=301,L]`
it worked perfectly. However for some odd reason, all other static requests are broken, like css/js its interfering with them. But I think you've put me on the right track. I'll keep you posted. Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Finally got it to work, just slightly tweaked what you gave me :

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ en/$1.html [R=301,L]`
`RewriteRule ^((en|ru))/?(.*)$ index.php?c=$1&q=$3 [L,QSA]`

I also used this website to test my code, made my life easier :)  http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/